# MYSQL mixing up dates

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying to insert a date in my Database which I get from a php input.
The code I am using to insert the value looks like this

```
$length = strrpos($fristdatum, " ");
$newDate = explode(".", substr($fristdatum, $length));
$fristdatum = $newDate[2] . "-" . $newDate[1] . "-" . $newDate[0];
```

Lets say I enter `14.12.2012` as the date if I `echo $fristdatum` I get `2012-12-14` but as soon as I insert it in my MySQL DB it turn to `2014.12.20` any ideas?

The Column Type is date. The insert is somewhat like this

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO sch_anschreiben (date)values('$fristdatum'))
```

there are more values but I guess that doesn't matter

Thanks in Advance!

Well thanks for the help guys i figured it out i used `$fristdatum` in a array for `str_replace` ,after i formated it, like this

```
$patern = array("[Date]")
$words=array($fristdatum)
$content = str_replace($patern, $words, $content);
```

and after that inserted it in the DB now I changed it so it would format after the `str_replace` and it seems to work just fine.
also would appreciate if someone could explain me why^^.

Comment: what is the type of column in database?

Comment: Can I see the code where it inserts in your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of explode and hard coded conversion, prefere using `DateTime::createFromFormat` if you have PHP 5.3 or later.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d. m. Y',$fristdatum);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');//echoes 2012-12-14
```

Now that you correct your script to register your dates the right way, you should ensure your database is good.
You can use this request I think :

```
UPDATE yourtable SET yourdate=CONCAT(MONTH(yourdate),'-',DAY(yourdate),'-',YEAR(yourdate)) WHERE MONTH(yourdate) > 12
```

Comment: well thats a nice optimization still if I echo the $date i get the right value but the value i get in my DB is wrong for some reason

Comment: I added some code to modify your database and make your dates correct

Answer (score 0):

The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.

The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

So if you want to store it like `14-12-2012` then use its datatype as `varchar`.

Comment: sry i just changed my post because i didnt make my self exactly clear i didnt mind storing it in yyyy-mm-dd format but as u see i switch the arrays so it turn from 14.12.2012 to 2012-12-14 but it still saves it as 2014-12-20 for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Convert it into Y-M-D format. You should directly put 2012-12-14 onto your database.

Comment: thats what i try to do with this line
$fristdatum = $newDate[2] . "-" . $newDate[1] . "-" . $newDate[0];

Comment: Check it by *copying pasting* your output value directly to your database table.